# Python. I'm creating a phone database and linking it with a python code

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a Python code that searches my sql database. I can make it search the phone model and display the duration of the contract. The problem is that when I try to make it display the price of each tariff, it returns error #1064. I figured out that the column name: "Price/Month" causes error in python so I changed it to PriceperMonth; but this error occurs. 
Example of Price per Month:
£ 25.

It has currency symbol. Maybe that is the one that causes the error.

My code:

```
#!/Python27/python
import mysql.connector

def SearchPhoneByPhone(Model):

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', \
    host='127.0.0.1', database ='phone')

cur = conn.cursor()

query = "SELECT phone.Model, tariff.Duration price.PriceperMonth FROM phone, tariff, price \
WHERE phone.Phone_ID = price.Phone_ID AND tariff.Tariff_ID = price.Tariff_ID \
AND phone.Model LIKE '%" + Model + "%'"

cur.execute(query)

print "This model " + Model +" has the following tariffs:"
for (Model, Duration, PriceperMonth) in cur.fetchall():
    print Model + " (Duration of the Contract: " + Duration + ")" + " (Price per Month: " + PriceperMonth + ")"
print ""

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

SearchPhoneByPhone('iPhone 6 Plus')

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ren25\Dropbox\SAT-0400 Project\Phone Database Connect.py", line 25, in <module>
SearchPhoneByPhone('iPhone 6 Plus')
File "C:\Users\Ren25\Dropbox\SAT-0400 Project\Phone Database Connect.py", line 15, in SearchPhoneByPhone
cur.execute(query)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 515, in execute
self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query
result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
raise errors.get_exception(packet)
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.PriceperMonth FROM phone, tariff, price     WHERE phone.Phone_ID = price.Phone_' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget comma between these 2 columns in select query:

```
tariff.Duration, price.PriceperMonth
```

so your query should be:

```
query = "SELECT phone.Model, tariff.Duration, price.PriceperMonth FROM phone, tariff, price \
WHERE phone.Phone_ID = price.Phone_ID AND tariff.Tariff_ID = price.Tariff_ID \
AND phone.Model LIKE '%" + Model + "%'"
```